# Elliptic PDE with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations

Given a connected bounded open domain $U$ with a smooth boundary and the following homogeneous Neumann boundary-value problem
\begin{cases}
\nabla [a(x) \nabla u(x)] = 0 & \text{in } U \newline
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0 & \text{on } \partial U
\end{cases}
where $a:U\mapsto\mathbb{R}^+$ is a smooth function.

Are the only smooth solutions constant?

I have found several proofs and statements for constant $a(x)$, i.e.,
for the Laplace equation, but none for elliptic PDEs. It sounds like a basic problem to me, but I did not find it in the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger and neither in that by Evans. Of course, I also searched in math stackexchange and beyond, but without
success. Since I am new to the study of PDEs, I may miss essential keywords or subtle details.

A reference would be a great help to me.

Comment: Hörmander deals with general linear partial differential equations.

Comment: Suppose $a>0$ on $\bar{U}$ and consider the 1d case with $U=(0,1)$. In this situation $u'(x) = c/a(x)$ where $c$ is a constant. The condition $u'(0)$ requires $c=0$, so the general solution is $u$ being constant, which also satisfies the Neumann condition at $x=1$.

Comment: I skimmed parts of Hörmander's books but did not find much on the Neumann problem. Is there a standard reference for (elliptic) PDEs with Neumann boundary conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a \in L^\infty(U)$ then $u$ is a constant. Indeed, if you multiply your equation by the solution $u$ then integrate by parts then you obtain that $$0=\int_U u \operatorname{div}(a\nabla u ) \, dx =-\int_Ua \vert \nabla u \vert^2\,dx + \int_{\partial U}au \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} \, dx =-\int_Ua \vert \nabla u \vert^2\,dx.$$ Since $a>0$ and $U$ is connected, we must have that $u$ is a constant in $U$.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. That is a great help to me. The argument even holds if $a$ vanishes at the boundary. Only if $a\not\in L^{\infty}(U)$, e.g., if it diverges at the boundary, then the surface term might not vanish. In that case, the answer depends on the speed of convergence of the normal derivative. Correct?

Comment: @wheat Yes, precisely. Though some care needs to be taken since the behaviour of $u$ (and hence $\partial u/ \partial \nu$) depends on $a$, but say you knew *a priori* some bound on the growth of $u$ close to the boundary then you're correct